# What's the difference between these two code?

Tags: javascript

```
while(todoList.children[0] !=null){
    todoList.children[0].remove();
}
```

```
for(let i = 0 ; i<todoList.childElementCount ; i++){
    console.log(i);
    todoList.children[0].remove();
}
```

I have a list and it has 5 elements in it. I want to remove elements from it. If i try to reach lists element count it gives 5 value with no problem .When i use while loop it works but for loop just runs 3 times.

Comment: In the second version, when you remove a child element the list gets shorter by one, but the loop still increments `i`. Thus elements are skipped.

Comment: The difference is, that the size of list in the for loop is checked once and runs x times. The first loop runs until the list is empty, while the size is checked every times.

Comment: If you want to remove all the child elements of a particular element, just set its `innerHTML` to an empty string. `todoList.innerHTML = ''`

Comment: Personally if I used the while version I would use `todoList.children.length` instead.  `0` being the falsy value to break out of the loop

Comment: A for loop runs for the number of iterations set in the initial conditions (the for statement).
A while loop runs while some condition set in the initial while statement is still true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way would be to store the `todoList.childElementCount` first in a new variable, and use that variable in the terminating condition of `for-loop`.

Or if you do not want to store `todoList.childElementCount` in a new variable, then:

```js
for(let i =  todoList.childElementCount-1; i>=0 ; i--){
    console.log(i);
    todoList.children[0].remove();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much  , i didn't even thought it our count changes dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the same if code was:

```
let initialChildCount = todoList.childElementCount;
for(let i = 0 ; i < initialChildCount; i++){
    console.log(i);
    todoList.children[0].remove();
}
```

In your code you keep decreasing `todoList.childElementCount` therefore loop ends faster

Answer (score 0):

`todoList.children[0]` is same as `todoList.firstChild`

```
while(todoList.children[0] !=null){
     todoList.children[0].remove();
}
```

looks up if the todolist has ONE child, and if so, then it removes it.

```
for(let i = 0 ; i<todoList.childElementCount ; i++){
    console.log(i);
    todoList.children[0].remove();
}
```

looks up every single time HOW MANY childs there are and then removes the firstchild. So therefore it is not that performant.

Comment: Doesn't explain different result produced

Comment: Oh I oversaw that. Children also can be textNodes. ChildElements are Dom Nodes